# Custom web fonts translating on emails, mobile email builders, and best HTML branded template builders

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, mailchimp

In general, I am trying to find the easiest way to incorporate our brand look which uses the Google font Raleway into emails without having to create the emails from scratch. I am sampling various programs to figure out the easiest route. In the example of using Mailchimp, when I attempt to add CSS to the top of the email body, it works on h1 - h5 headers but the paragraph body text does not. For the text that is translating, it does go through to my desktop Gmail preview, but not to my mobile phone preview.

I realize that not all email servers deliver custom web fonts regardless of the device, but I seem to find other sources that say it is possible to code in, yet I see inconsistent answers on the right CSS and I have tried some but none that work yet. I trialled another program called GetResponse which did everything I needed except still can't get the mobile to show the code I need. Is this even possible to code in?

Looking for any advice in this area - Also if there is an easy HTML template builder that anyone could recommend (such as Envato Market email templates) if this is an easier route, I am open to that but everything I looked at I have to purchase and there is no trial. I know some HTML/CSS but by no means an expert.

Below is a copy of the CSS I used in Mailchimp that works for h1-h5 but not on p text and not on the mobile version, and nothing will show properly on the mobile device. Overall, hoping for any advice on incorporating the code to translate to all devices if this is even possible, and if not, if a custom HTML email builder can generate this as a workaround or not.

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap');
p {font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; letter-spacing:0.1em;}
</style>
```

Comment: I wish you all the luck you need for this endeavour.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Gmail doesn't support Google fonts.

If you want to hand-code the email I would advise you to check out this [article](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts) from Litmus on the topic.

Otherwise, I would advise you to check out this [email builder](https://chamaileon.io) (Chamaileon), it has the Raleway font built-in with several fallbacks.

Comment: I appreciate the information you shared, I will look into all of that. Thank you!